# Can't connect existing AppSync resolvers/API to existing Dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have existing an AppSync API, and I want connect it to an existing Dynamodb table. However, I cannot connect with Dynamodb without creating a new AppSync API.

I created new AppSync API and AWS allow me to connect with existing Dynamodb.

[The official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/import-dynamodb.html) stated that I can choose New button, but I can't found it. Here's the image [image]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation misleads me. You have to click on Create data source, choose Data source type is Amazon DynamoDB Table, and choose the region of your existing table.
After that the table name dropdown will appear and you can pick your existing table from that.